# trac authentication issue with mercurial

Tags: mercurial, authentication, trac

I'm trying to get a Trac install working on a Centos box. I have installed Trac (v 0.12.1) and tracmercurial plugin (http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMercurial) rev #@9946.

So far everything seems to be working fine EXCEPT when i go to the login page. I constantly get the error

```
"Authentication information not available."
```

My trac project is at **/home/adil/trac-projects** . My mercurial repo is at **/home/adil/hg/reponame** . My htpasswd file is at **/home/adil/hg/.htpasswd**, world readable.

I would like to use my htpasswd file to login to trac, but as soon as i step in the page i am greeted with a friendly error. I am initializing tracd like so :

```
sudo tracd --port 8002 --basic-auth=\"trac-projects,/home/adil/hg/.htpasswd,Private\" /home/adil/trac-projects
```

The reason i mentioned mercurial is because it seemed to work when the plugin was not installed. But i need both.

What gives?

Comment: Why did you quote your basic-auth value? Apart from that it conforms to the reference wiki docs at http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone#BasicAuthorization:Usingahtpasswdpasswordfile, as you'll most probably know. At least it shouldn't be a permission issue, because you start with sudo. Looks not immediately clear. - By chance, would you consider trying another plugin, if you could get this working? http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin is known for handling a great variety of password stores, including htpasswd format style files and variants. Would give more details then...